# Paperclip allow users to upload pictures of 800x500 and above in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

I created a file entitle in my models called **dimensions_validator.rb**

```
class DimensionsValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator


    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        if record.send("#{attribute}?".to_sym)
          dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(value.queued_for_write[:original].path)
          width = options[:width]
          height = options[:height]

          record.errors[attribute] << "Width must be at least #{width}px" unless dimensions.width = width
          record.errors[attribute] << "Height must be at least #{height}px" unless dimensions.height = height
        end
      end
    end
```

And in my **Product** model i do

```
validates :image, dimensions: { width: 800, height: 500 }
```

> **Question:** How can allow users to upload pictures of 800x500 and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace conditions and messages in these lines:

```
record.errors[attribute] << "Width must be at least #{width}px" if dimensions.width < width
record.errors[attribute] << "Height must be at least #{height}px" if dimensions.height < height
```

Comment: U must use `==` in conditions. Read in Internet difference between `=` and `==` in Ruby.

Comment: so where should i use the 2 equal signs? something like this `dimensions.width >= width` ?

Comment: Yes, in `unless` conditions.

Comment: I changed condition operators and `unless` statement to `if`. Now, validator should works as you expected.

Comment: Everything works,but `dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(value.queued_for_write[:original].path)` gives an error,if i submit the form without selecting an image,Would you know how to fix it?